# How to display HTTP error messages on ionic app?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is there a standard way of showing error messages on ionic mobile app. 
From the documentation I couldn't find any information associated with showing error messages.

Doc referred: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider you want to send all HTTP errors to Modal  you can override exceptions by using `$provide decorator "$exceptionHandler"` :

```
$provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", function($delegate, $injector)   {
        return function(exception, cause) {
           /* here you can do what u want  */
  });
```

To send  to native code or even to Crashlytics (reporting server) use Cordova bridge:

```
app.config(function($provide) {

    $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", function($delegate, $injector) {
        return function(exception, cause) {

            if (false) { //(appState !== "...") { // We want to only send the error in this case

                $delegate(exception, cause);

            } else {
                //appState == null;

                var MyCordovaService = $injector.get("MyCordovaService");

                console.debug({reason: exception, message: exception.message, stack: exception.stack});

                var data = {
                    message: "Exception: " + exception.message,
                    stack: exception.stack || "none"
                };

                MyCordovaService.reportClientError(data).then(function(data) {
                    console.debug('reportClientError success', data);
                }, function(error) {
                    console.debug('reportClientError fail!', error);
                });
                //}



                // Call The original Angular Exception Handler
                $delegate(exception, cause);
            }
        };
    });

});
```

---

Demo in <kbd>[Codepan](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Yydywx)</kbd>

---

Hope it will help,

Comment: I couldn't grasp much out of your code. It would be really helpful if you can post a demo error message generation in a fiddle page.

Comment: added demo with alert

Comment: Thanks. How to show the error message to the user in an intuitive manner something similar to what bootstrap offers.

Comment: it should be popup or I would send it to native and show as toast. also u have cordova plugin Toasts. Anyways this is a answer on your question.